# Atribuir cor de fundo na DIV quando ordenar por ordem alfabética no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Boa noite!

Estou tentando montar uma lista da seguinte maneira:

```
<div>
  <div>id</div>
  <div><a id="orderStatus">status</a></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="listStatus" style="background-color:#fff">
    <div>C</div>
    <div>1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="listStatus" style="background-color:#DCDCDC">C</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="listStatus" style="background-color:#FFF">A</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="acao" value="asc" />
</div>
```

O formato que é impresso é o mesmo de uma tabela, porém com div's.

Para facilitar a visualização da linha, eu crei uma linha com background FFF e a outra DCDCDC e assim por diante, ficando 'cor sim, cor não', porém quando eu faço a ordenação, as cores ordenam juntos fazendo com que a funcionalidade da cor perca o objetivo, que é facilitar a visualização.

Há alguma maneira de fazer a correção da cor na função abaixo?

```
    $("#orderStatus").click(function(){
        var acao = $('#acao').val();
        var statusList = $(".listStatus");
        statusList.sort(function(a, b) {
            if(acao == "asc"){
                $('#acao').val('desc');
                var res = $(b).attr("status") > $(a).attr("status");
            }
            else{
                $('#acao').val('asc');
                var res = $(a).attr("status") > $(b).attr("status");
            }
            return res;

        });

        $('#container').html(statusList);
    });
```

Comment: O certo seria você usar css para montar o esquema de 'cor sim e cor não'. Usando `nth-child(even)` ao invés de `style`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro fazeres isso com CSS e tirar a lógica das cores do HTML:

```css
#container div div:nth-child(2n){
     background-color: #dcdcdc;
    }
    
    #container div div:nth-child(2n + 1){
     background-color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div>
    <div>id</div>
    <div><a id="orderStatus">status</a></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="listStatus">
        <div>C</div>
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="listStatus">C</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="listStatus">A</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="acao" value="asc" />
</div>
```

Comment: Acabei me explicando mal e o entendimento foi outro, a saida que eu desejo é a seguinte
`id | status
 c  | 1
 c  | 2
 a  | 3`
Onde id e status são uma linha, c e 1 são outra linha, c e 2 são outro linha , e por fim, a e 3 são uma outra linha. A solução acima faz com que as colunas mudem de cor. Mas agradeço pela dica, não sabia que dava para fazer isso no CSS3

Comment: @BrunoFolle ok, então poderias fazer assim: https://jsfiddle.net/zw50xtx0/1/ também só com CSS...

Comment: Sergio, deu certo!!! Muito Obrigado!